# Using AssertEquals in a static method in python

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, assert

I am learning to code in Python and have hit a bit of a wall.  I am trying to create a static method to reuse in a series of tests, and I cannot seem to get a unit test to work within the method.  Before moving to the static method the test functioned as below:

```
self.assertEqual(api_object.status_code, 200, "\nNot getting a 200\n")
```

within the static method I have tried several possible solutions, but with little success.  I have confirmed that the value being passed in is a definite match.  A quick summary of variations and failures(and my debug process).  Sorry I cannot provide more code, work sensitive stuff:

```
assertEqual(api_object.status_code, 200, "\nNot getting a 200\n")
```

error:  global name assertEqual is undefined.  To rectify I tried:

```
TestCase.assertEqual(api_object.status_code, 200, "Not getting a 200 back")
```

TypeError: unbound method assertEqual() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got int instance instead).  So I tried:

```
TestCase.assertEqual(TestCase, api_object.status_code, 200, "Not getting a 200 back")
```

TypeError: unbound method assertEqual() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got type instance instead).

At this point I'm a bit stumped.  I am using the Django framework.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what's going on here.  `assertEqual` is a method of TestCase -- It should be called on the test case currently testing stuff.  I suppose one question is why are you moving this call into a "staticmethod" in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big question here is *why you are using static methods in the first place*.

Don't try to use methods from `TestCase` here. You could just use `assert` here:

```
assert api_object.status_code == 200, "Not getting a 200 back"
```

You can't call `TestCase.assertEqual()` without an actual `TestCase` instance in any case as the method expects to be able to call other methods on `self`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn -- Makes sense now.  As to why I am using static, we are looking at building a library and this would be one of the methods used to set up our tests.  Since there is no need to manipulate the object beyond this assertion and a quick process that does not change it made sense to me to set it up as static.

Comment: In case anyone finds themselves here now, I disagree with the recommendation to use assert. Test case methods provide consistency with other tests, and other developer friendliness. Instead I recommend just instantiating a test case and calling the method like so:  `TestCase().assertEqual(a,b)`

Comment: @theannouncer sure, but the question was how to do this in a static method :-) I also did prefix my answer with *The big question here is why you are using static methods in the first place.* for a reason.

Comment: @theannouncer last but certainly not least: All TestCase assertion methods raise AssertionError on failure, just like `assert` does, there is no inconsistency here.

Comment: My suggestion was to instantiate TestCase within your static method. assertEquals output is much clearer when debugging, assert depends on the author to write a nice message.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn is right: instance methods from `TestCase` like `assertEqual()` need to be called from an instance of `TestCase`, so you can't just move them to a static method and expect them to work. Notice how your original method had

```
self.assertEqual(api_object.status_code, 200, "\nNot getting a 200\n")
```

where `self` presumably referred to a `TestCase` instance. This means somewhere in `TestCase`'s implementation there's a method definition like this:

```
def assertEqual(self, testValue, expectedValue, errorMsg):
```

Note how in Python class methods, a reference to the invoking instance is always included as the first argument (`self`). This is why when you try calling the method without a `TestCase` instance, you got the error "TypeError: unbound method assertEqual() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got int instance instead)."

However, I note that you say you want to "reuse your static method in a series of tests," and those tests are presumably `TestCase` instances like your original non-static method. If that's the case, you could write your static method like this:

```
def runCommonTests(testInstance, other_args):
    api_object = get_api_object_somehow()
    ...
    testInstance.assertEqual(api_object.status_code, 200, "Not getting a 200 back")
```

Then in your non-static, `TestCase` method, you would call the static method and pass it the current `TestCase` instance to work with. So where you originally had the `self.assertEqual()` line, you would write

```
runCommonTests(self, other_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it is good for you to get familiar with the difference between class method and static method.

Basically class methods takes instance for first argument, but static methods not.